# How to create this document with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, exercises

Good morning friends;
I would be very grateful if you help me create this [TD10](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8SIeknO-aIhcS1wcGxYVENVVkk) document with tikz. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. If you provide links to Google Drive you should assure that others can access it ;-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Please post the image here and not on an external site so that this question is independent of the external link.  Also, It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem and shows what you have tried so far so that it is clear where you are stuck. That way, perhaps this question can perhaps be helpful to others in the future, as opposed to a _do this for me_ type of question.

Comment: TikZ really isn't suitable for this, in my opinion. But since you say you did it, certainly you should share the code! Elements might be well done in TikZ, although perhaps not necessary, but I wouldn't put the main content of that document inside a TikZ picture.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? Tikz is good for graphics, so some of the elements in your document can be done with it, but not everything. Besides, it's not the only tool that can be used for this.

`\Startex` adds a new exercise title. The counter is automatic, just add the command when you want a new exercise to start.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textsc{page}~\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}

\newcounter{numex}

\def\thrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr1pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}

\newcommand\Startex{%
    \stepcounter{numex}
    \begin{center}
    \thrulefill~\textsc{\bfseries Exercise~\thenumex}~\thrulefill
    \end{center}
}

\newcommand\around{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw[rounded corners=5mm] ($(current page.south west)+(1cm,1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-1cm,-1cm)$);
        \node[fill=white, rotate=90, anchor=west, font=\footnotesize\scshape] at ($(current page.south west)+(1cm,2cm)$) {CPGE Lycée Med V};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\Title{
    \vspace{2cm}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \node[draw, rounded corners, align=center, text width=7cm, minimum height=1.5cm] (title) at (0,0) {TD 10\\\bfseries Fonctions convexes};
    \node[anchor=south west] (top) at (title.north west) {PCSI-2 — CPGE Lycée Med V};
    \draw (top.east) -- ($(top.east-|title.east)+(-5pt,0)$);
    \node[anchor=north east] (bottom) at (title.south east) {2015-2016};
    \draw (bottom.west) -- ($(bottom.west-|title.west)+(5pt,0)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{2cm}
}

\begin{document}
\around
\Title

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\Startex
\lipsum[1]

\Startex
\lipsum[2]

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```