# How to repeat this framework?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, exercises

How to repeat the command \around in every page automatically on this [page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296357). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could load `\usepackage[color=black,opacity=1,angle=0,scale=1]{background}` and then enclose the `\around` in the setup for setting the background. This requires some changes in the `\Title` command because the vertical space changes. So here is the complete solution.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[color=black,opacity=1,angle=0,scale=1]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textsc{page}~\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}

\newcounter{numex}

\def\thrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr1pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}

\newcommand\Startex{%
    \stepcounter{numex}
    \begin{center}
    \thrulefill~\textsc{\bfseries Exercise~\thenumex}~\thrulefill
    \end{center}
}

\backgroundsetup{
contents={%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw[rounded corners=5mm] ($(current page.south west)+(1cm,1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-1cm,-1cm)$);
        \node[fill=white, rotate=90, anchor=west, font=\footnotesize\scshape] at ($(current page.south west)+(1cm,2cm)$) {CPGE Lycée Med V};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
}

\newcommand\Title{
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \node[draw, rounded corners, align=center, text width=7cm, minimum height=1.5cm] (title) at (0,-2) {TD 10\\\bfseries Fonctions convexes};
    \node[anchor=south west] (top) at (title.north west) {PCSI-2 — CPGE Lycée Med V};
    \draw (top.east) -- ($(top.east-|title.east)+(-5pt,0)$);
    \node[anchor=north east] (bottom) at (title.south east) {2015-2016};
    \draw (bottom.west) -- ($(bottom.west-|title.west)+(5pt,0)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{4cm}
}

\begin{document}
\Title

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\Startex
\lipsum[1]

\Startex
\lipsum[2]

\Startex
\lipsum[3-5]

\Startex
\lipsum[5-8]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```